# Why isn't jQuery working on my local server

Tags: jquery

I'm a beginner of web coding. I tried to run my html with jquery on my local server with XAMPP, then I wanted to show that on browser(Safari, Chrome). html and css showed up but jquery didn't work. My code is for changing a background at regular intervals but anything wasn't moving.
macOS Mojave 10.14.6

I tried this on XAMPPforOSX(7.3.9)(not VM version), then turned on Apache Web Server and accessed http://localhost/ on Safari and Chrome.
I put jquery-3.4.1.min.js and my js file on a same directory.  And background photos were in the folder on the directory.

```
jQuery(window).on('load resize', function() {
  var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;

  if (windowWidth > 1024) {
    // desktop
    var i = 1;
    setInterval(function(){
      if(i<=6){
        jQuery("body").css("background-image","url('home/page" + i + "_desktop.jpeg')no-repeat fixed center center");
        i++;
      }
      else i = 1;
    }, 1000);
  }
```

and I placed all files on htdocs folder of XAMPP, then checked with Inspect mode on Chrome. I found out my folder for background images only included one image file(page1_desktop.jpeg). I'm sure that I put all images like page1_desktop.jpeg, page2_desktop.jpeg...
And my css is like this below

```
@media(max-width: 2000px){
  body {
    background-color: white;
    background: url("home/page1_desktop.jpg")no-repeat fixed 
center center;    
    background-size: cover;
  } 
}
```

Comment: If you look in the [browser console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers), it’ll show you the error. You can update this question with the error and we can try and help you.

Comment: Has the jquery js been downloaded properly? You can confirm this by opening the developer's screen network tab (F12). You might need to refresh the page

Comment: @ThomasEdwards thank you for reply. I tried it on the browser console then found a problem.

Comment: @Jayr I downloaded it on https://jquery.com/download/ . That was a compressed one. Then I've just opened the network tab, but i guess jquery file was downloaded.

Comment: @n_wolfdog, please confirm. The network tab and as mentioned by Thomas, browser console are your better friends. You should see that the js is being used by the html and is downloaded by the browser (no 404) at the very basic.

Comment: @Jayr I've just confirmed that the js file has been downloaded on the network tab. Then I opened debugger and triggered step-into. setInterval was called just once(not looped).

Comment: if you want it to loop 6 times, you need to use a loop inside setInterval.  As it is written now, it would only be called once, and only execute once, because nothing in your code tells it to repeat

Comment: @Gus but if I put "for loop" inside setInterval, that will mean changing the images 6 times then waiting 1 sec, right?